# How to use a dependency what are not part of Quarkus' BOM in Quarkus extension?

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, quarkus-extension

I'm trying to build a Quarkus extension that will use `quarkus-logging-json` from `io.quarkiverse.loggingjson`. This dependency is not a part of Quarkus BOM file. I cannot find any information how to add this kind of dependency into own extension in Quarkus' documents. I tried to do the same thing with Maven as is described for `quarkus-undertrow` but with

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkiverse.loggingjson</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-logging-json</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

https://quarkus.io/guides/building-my-first-extension#basic-version-of-the-sample-greeting-extension . I want to use `quarkus-logging-json` in my extension project.

Comment: Hope it helps: https://quarkus.io/extensions/io.quarkus/quarkus-logging-json
The `groupId` changed to `io.quarkus`.

Comment: I need specific implementation from io.quarkiverse.loggingjson - JsonProvider which is not part of io.quarkus

Comment: It should work to just add the dependency into your extension's pom.xml. Are you getting an error when you do that?

Comment: @HollyCummins when I trying to install it by maven I received following error: 
```Deployment artifact logging.quarkus:com-library-logging-java-quarkus-deployment::jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing the following dependencies from its configuration: io.quarkiverse.loggingjson:quarkus-logging-json-deployment::jar, io.quarkus:quarkus-jackson-deployment::jar, io.quarkus:quarkus-jsonb-deployment::jar